# How to change file permission from within vi

Tags: vim, vi

I sometimes open a read-only file in vi, forgetting to do `chmod +w` before opening it. Is there way to change the file from within vi?

Something like `!r chmod +w [filename]`?

Is there a shortcut to refer to the currently open file without spelling it's long name?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just use

```
:!chmod +w %
```

in command mode. % will be replaced by the current file name.

Comment: Thanks --- this was useful. A minor annoyance is that vim now warns about the need to reload the file (W16). Is there a way to stop it without setting autoread?

Comment: @Rmano I know it's an old post, but it's worth mentioning for posterity: You could use Tim Pope's Eunuch.vim and then use the `:Chmod` command. It does exactly what you're wanting.

Answer (score 39):

If you have the rights to write to the file, then you can just use exclamation mark to force it:

```
:w!
```

If you don't have the rights and need to change user, but still want to write to the file, sometimes you may go for something like

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Comment: You don't want to write to file all the time either ;-)

Comment: `:w !sudo tee %` sends the file input to `tee` which then forwards it to the current file `%`.

Comment: @LuboKanev, that's right. As a side effect `tee` also writes the file to console, but that's not meant to accomplish anything ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old post, but with Vim Version8 a function has been included with which you can change file permissions.

According to the version8.txt file:

> setfperm()        set the permissions of a file

This function can then be called via the "call" command in Vim.

This is done as follows:

```
:call setfperm("file name","permissions")
```

The structure of the "permissions" string takes the same form as described in the Vim documentation:

> getfperm({fname})                 *getfperm()*
>           The result is a String, which is the read, write, and execute
>           permissions of the given file {fname}.
>           If {fname} does not exist or its directory cannot be read, an
>           empty string is returned.
>           The result is of the form "rwxrwxrwx", where each group of
>           "rwx" flags represent, in turn, the permissions of the owner
>           of the file, the group the file belongs to, and other users.
>           If a user does not have a given permission the flag for this
>           is replaced with the string "-".  Example:
>               :echo getfperm("/etc/passwd")
>           This will hopefully (from a security point of view) display
>           the string "rw-r--r--" or even "rw-------".

A minimal example:

```
:call setfperm("foo.txt","rwxrwxrwx")
```

This adds read, write and execute permissions to the "foo.txt" file in the current directory.

Comment: `setfperm()` is also present in Vim 7 (at least, 7.4 has it). `:call setfperm(expand("%"), "rwxr-xr-x")` is one way to set the mode for the current file to 0755, without needing to enter the file's name explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried

```
!chmod +w %
```

The % represents the current filename.

You could also map a key to this like Ctrl-W.

```
:map <C-w> :!chmod +w %<CR>
```

Note that you type Ctrl-V Ctrl-M to get the `<CR>`

Answer (score 5):

After editing your file with vim, press "esc" and then ":".
Then type the following command:

```
w !sudo tee %
```

Then press "Enter".
Then type

```
:q!
```

to successfully exit from the editor.

Comment: Thanks @Kasumi! This is what I was looking for - how to switch the user and write the file using it's owner (root in my case).

Answer (score 1):

```
:!chmod <perms> <file>
```

and if vi still doesn't want to write it,

```
:se cpo-=W
```

Answer (score 0):

As David pointed out, setfperm() is the way to do this within vim.

Here are the mappings I use to add write or execute permissions to the current file:

```
function! ChmodPlus(expr, pat)
    let file = expand('%')
    let oldperms = getfperm(file)
    let newperms = substitute(oldperms, a:expr, a:pat, '')
    if (oldperms != newperms)
        call setfperm(file, newperms)
    endif
    echom(printf('Permissions: %s', newperms))
endfunction

function! ChmodPlusX()
    call ChmodPlus('^\(..\).', '\1x')
endfunction

function! ChmodPlusW()
    call ChmodPlus('^\(.\).', '\1w')
endfunction

" Make current file writeable
noremap <silent> <Leader>W :call ChmodPlusW()<CR>

" Make current file executable
noremap <silent> <Leader>X :call ChmodPlusX()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the netrw module that comes with vim if your lazy, example `:Texplore` followed by scrolling to the file in normal mode and entering `gp`. Octal or symbolic at least work.

It's a little more intuitive with multiple files but per buffer-window without, use your colon command history to repeat commands.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ideas from several answers here, I'm now using this:

```
" autoreload file
set autoread

" chmod +x current file
"
" not using setfperm() here to have the behavior of chmod(1), e.g. adding and
" using the umask.
function! ChmodThis(perm)
  if getbufinfo('%')[0].changed
    echo "Modified, save first!"
  else
    call system('chmod ' .. a:perm .. ' -- ' .. expand('%:S'))
    echo "chmod done."
  endif
endfunction
noremap <silent> <Leader>X :call ChmodThis('+x')<CR>
```